# How can I set a scroll value less than 1 in marquee tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html4

My html code:

```
 <marquee align="middle" behavior="scroll" loop="infinite"  direction="up" width="230" height="150" scrollamount="0.5" onmouseover="this.scrollAmount=0" onmouseout="this.scrollAmount=1" border="0" TRUESPEED>
```

Comment: Note that the marquee tag isn't a valid HTML tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). It's better practice to use JavaScript or CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

```
<marquee behavior=scroll direction="left" scrollamount="1">Your message here</marquee>
```

The above code will do scrolling slowly.The "1" is smallest value .

Comment: And scrollamount can not be less than =>  "1"

Answer (score 0):

Scrollamount can not be less than, One of the work around is to use scrolldelay="700" (edit this value as per your requirement)